# Android ProgressDialog OnClickListener with Back button issue

Tags: android, progressdialog, onclicklistener

I am having some tab-type activities where a user can navigate from one activity to another, on clicking button tabs in the top. When clicking on any of the tabs, a ProgressDialog appears, with a "Loading..." view. I want to manage it, because during the loading process, if a user presses the back button it goes back to the previous activity.

I have tried implementing this using ProgressDialog's onClickListener, but I am having 2 issues.

**First** issue is during the loading dialog: If user clicks anywhere on the screen the onClickListener of progress dialog triggers. I don't want this to happen; it should only be triggered from back the button.

**Second** issue is when "Loading..." appears, my onClickListener works for 1 or 1.5 seconds while it is visible for around 2-3 seconds. If I press the back button after 1 or 1.5 sec. the progress dialog listener does not do anything and remains on the same activity?

Comment: just got the solution of first issue..just used progressdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: Nice to see that. But I think your main issue is that you don't want your progress dialog to go back to previous screen when back button is clicked. More than that, I think you dont need much. just do pd.setCancellable(false); .. and remove every thing else from your code. Even your click listener as well. and try that.

Comment: @BratRosm no you are mistaken my friend..its just opposite,i want to go back to previous screen only with back button and nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

override `onBackPressed()` method and dismiss your dialog first and then let the `super.onBackPressed()` work, this way it will close your dialog and you can go back to the normal screen.

Secondly, just set `dialog.setCancellable(false);`, that way a user will not be able to do even if he/she clicks on any place of the screen.

For example,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 dialog.dismiss();
 super.onBackPressed();
}

void create ProgressDialog() {
 dialog =  new ProgressDialog/Alerdialog.Builder(this);
 dialog.setTitle(tile);
 dialog.setMessage(message);
 dialog.setCancellable(false);
 dialog.show();
}
```

All good to go!

Comment: :: neither OnBackPressed nor OnKeyDown works if the progressDialog is visible...not a useful trick for me

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem :

```
  public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (pDialog != null)
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                return;

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```